# Show next data after button is pressed

Tags: json, swift, swiftui

I am loading some data from a json file. I am trying to load the next set of data when a button is pressed however I can't seem to figure out how to add an action to the button that will load the next set of data when the button is pressed. Ideally, it would be nice to load the next set of data by the index (`_id`)

Currently, as the code is written, only the first set of data will load. However, I am not sure how to load the next set of data

LabelData

```
import Foundation

struct LabelData: Codable {

    var _id: Int
    var _name: String
    var _type: String
    var _description: String
    var label: String
}
```

ContentView

```
import SwiftUI



struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                print("Red Action")
                }) {
                    Text("R")
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                        .background(Color.red)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                }

                        }
            VStack{
                if let test = labels.first {
                    VStack {
                        Text(test._name)
                    }
                    VStack {
                        Text(test._type)
                    }
                    VStack {
                        Text(test._type)
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            .offset(x: 0, y: -100)
        }

    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

DataLoader

```
import Foundation

var labels: [LabelData] = load("labeldata.json")

func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> T {
    let data: Data

    guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
        else {
            fatalError("Couldn't find \(filename) in main bundle.")
    }

    do {
        data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't load \(filename) from main bundle:\n\(error)")
    }

    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't parse \(filename) as \(T.self):\n\(error)")
    }
}
```

labeldata

```
[
    {
        "_id" : 1,
        "_name" : "Label1",
        "_type" : "type1",
        "_description" : "description1",
        "label" : ""
    },
    {
        "_id" : 2,
        "_name" : "Label2",
        "_type" : "type2",
        "_description" : "description2",
        "label" : ""
    }
]
```

Comment: You can access the `labels` array using subscripting such as `labels[0]` you just need to store the index that you are on in an `@State` variable and update it by 1 each time you press the button.

Comment: something is not quite right with the code you are showing us, what is `labels` in your `ContentView`. Where does it come from?  Are you showing us the "real" code or some made up thing? Also `....Currently, as the code is written, only the first set of data will load....`, well this is what you have `labels.first`, what do you expect from that? Is your question about how to iterate though an array? If so, read the basics again at: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine that comes from the `DataLoader`. You are correct, with `labels.first` will only show the first set of data. I just wanted to point that out just so everyone knew that I recognize that the current code will only show the first set of data

Comment: so I was right, you don't know how to iterate though an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this approach to iterate through the array of `LabelData`:

```
struct LabelData: Codable {
    var _id: Int
    var _name: String
    var _type: String
    var _description: String
    var label: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var labels: [LabelData] = []
    // for testing
    //    [
    //        LabelData(_id: 0, _name: "name1", _type: "type1", _description: "description1", label: "www"),
    //        LabelData(_id: 1, _name: "name2", _type: "type2", _description: "description2", label: "zz"),
    //        LabelData(_id: 2, _name: "name3", _type: "type3", _description: "description3", label: "xx")
    //    ]
    
    // index into the labels array
    @State var index = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: { index += 1 }) {
                if index < labels.count {
                    VStack {
                        Text(labels[index]._name)
                        Text(labels[index]._type)
                        Text(labels[index]._description)
                    }
                } else {
                    Text("R")
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            .background(Color.red)
            .clipShape(Circle())
        }
        .onAppear {
            labels = load("TestFile")
        }
    }
    
    func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename: String) -> T {
        let data: Data
        guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
        else {
            fatalError("Couldn't find \(filename) in main bundle.")
        }
        do {
            data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Couldn't load \(filename) from main bundle:\n\(error)")
        }
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Couldn't parse \(filename) as \(T.self):\n\(error)")
        }
    }
    
}
```